# My previous and Next button tend to fluctuate up and down when moving to the next page with a larger body of words

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, padding

So, I am coming across a slight problem with my buttons, basically when I click the next button and the page has more body words then the buttons tend to move vertically downwards and back to upwards with less words on a page.

```css
.azibsButtons {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="azibsButtons">
  <button type="button" id="previous" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Prev</button>

  <button type="button" id="next" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Next</button>

  <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
</div>
```

I need the buttons to be stable in one position please.

Comment: Try using position:absolute on .azibsButtons

Comment: No, it didn't help, the buttons got attached together and still moving vertically up and down @Chiller

Comment: Try to add a height for the content area and set to overflow-y:scroll

Comment: you need to specify the position top/left .. try adding top 50px; for example

Comment: Yeah i tried but the button still move up & down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood correctly you want the buttons to be fixed even when the page load new text correct?

well if the content isn't contained withing some kind of a (frame) then the button will go up and down depending how long the text is, that's just how the web works.

but you can set the height of the text's container `height: 200px;` and allow the scroll bar using 
`overflow-y: scroll;` this way now matter how long the text is the container height is fixed

Comment: I put a height on it and now the buttons are not moving! Great! but whats the overflow-y: scroll; do i need it?

Comment: Okay the height : 200px; works but when i refresh the page it goes back to how it was. Why is the height: 200px; not saving?

Comment: in case the text was too big, way too big the `overflow-y: scroll` will put a scroll bar on the right so the text is contained within that element (div?) , think of it as a frame, if you know that the text won't be too long then  setting the `height` with few extra pixels will do the trick

Comment: why is my height not saving ? as soon as i refresh my heigh:200px; changes back to normal @kapreski

Comment: can you please add your entire page css and html (no sensitive info) in this https://jsfiddle.net/sxvsc0t0/ and save so I can help

Comment: How do i save ?

Comment: don't worry, I've created a new [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5nabe7v8/4/) for you, check it out

Comment: .form-group {
   
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 100px;
  
}

Comment: this i where i am putting the height

Comment: I guess `.form-group` is the main container?
no you need to wrap the text itself in a div or a span and then add the height to that span. 
for example `<span class='textContainer'> some text... </span>` 
after that you add the buttons element.. so when you style 
`.textContainer { height: 100px;}` the height of the invisible span is what pushes the button element downward and because its height is fixed `100px` the buttons elements stay in place as long as the text is not too big for the span.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here we go. So you dont want the buttons moving, so the solution I came up with is to put div elements around your text:

```
<div class="text">
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent faucibus porta lectus at elementum. Morbi purus ligula, vestibulum nec accumsan id, dignissim vestibulum leo. Vestibulum eu sapien eros. Phasellus tristique convallis tortor in ornare. Duis euismod lectus enim. Vestibulum pulvinar felis eget ex posuere molestie. Phasellus molestie magna at orci elementum blandit. Curabitur laoreet molestie sapien, in rutrum purus sollicitudin vel.

    </p>
</div>
```

then create a class, in this case, text.

```
.text {
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
}
```

This should be set to be the max height of your biggest piece of text. Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjzzLLv2/1/)

Comment: Im gonna try it

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Like what exactly isnt working etc

Comment: Well everything is working fine just the button in the button do not want them to move. And it's fixed now thanks